# best practice to write bdd cucumber feature/ scenarios together with user

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I have an question when I practice TDD cucumber java.

1. In order for developer like me to work together with business user or project manager, where shall the feature file stored? Confluence ? GIT/SVN?

If we store feature files in confluence, we probably need to synchronise these files from time to time.

If we store feature GIT/SVN, don't think business user/PM know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A feature file has two major stages in its lifecycle. When its first being created its a collabaritive document that wants to be shared between all the involved parties. At this point in its life you can treat it like a user story.

The second stage is when the feature is implemented. As soon as you start running scenarios from it the feature is now code. This means it really should be stored in a SCM system (GIT), and it now belongs to development (they should be able to refactor it).

The difficult part is when review takes place and suggests that a feature should be changed somehow. Here you need the developer to talk directly to the reviewer and take responsibility for making the relevant scenarios available for discussion and refinement.

One thing that makes all of this much easier is the writing of highly abstract scenarios. These remove all the detail of how something is done, and instead focus on scenarios/features describing WHAT is done and WHY its important. In this way features are used much less in review, as the vast majority of review is about HOW something is done.